# Install Debian Linux on a Fujitsu Esprimo D7010

Tags: debian, efi, secure-boot

After installing Debian Linux on a Fujitsu Esprimo D7010, there is no corresponding boot entry visible. The new Debian installation cannot be booted. It appears the problem is related to secure boot.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It actually has nothing to do with secure boot, at least not directly. It is this problem:

https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Force_grub-efi_installation_to_the_removable_media_path

So choose "Expert Install" in the installer and close to the end of the installation process, answer "Force GRUB installation to the EFI removable media path?" with YES.